# Checking if select statement in stored procedure returns row

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, aggregate-functions

How does one check if a select statement inside a stored procedure returns any rows.

```
select * from creditcards;
If sqlcod = 0 THEN
```

I'd like to do something like this for example but sqlcod doesn't seem to work in MySql.

Comment: `sqlcod` isn't a keyword in MySQL, or any other database that I'm aware of.  Check the code you got it from, it's a variable from something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try using `COUNT`,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procName()
BEGIN
    SET @recCount = (select count(*) from creditcards);
    If @recCount = 0 THEN
        -- statement here ;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using like below also:

Use `FOUND_ROWS()` and `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

create procedure myproc() 
begin 
   SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * 
   FROM tbl_name 
   WHERE id > 100 
   LIMIT 10; 

   if SELECT FOUND_ROWS() = 0 then 
   -- log away bro! 
   end if; 
end $$
DELIMITER $$
```